# Converting mysql date to NSDate

Tags: mysql, swift, date, datetime

Using JSON, I'm pulling a date from my database which is formatted as Y-m-d in php. E.g. 2015-05-27.

I have stored the date in swift and can see it formatted when I print the string in the same way. I have followed the other answers and tutorials to try and convert the date into dd-MM-yyyy, but each time I am returned 'nil'.

If I try to convert the date to yyyy-MM-dd I will get '2015-05-26 23:00:00 +0000'

My code:

```
var survey_date = prefs.valueForKey("SURVEY_DATE") as! String

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(survey_date) as NSDate!

println(date)

self.survey_date.text = "Your survey is scheduled for \(date)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your date formatter's `dateFormat` property to `dd-MM-yyyy`, but the string in `survey_date` formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`.  As a result, the value for date in this line...

```
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(survey_date) as NSDate!
```

is `nil`. That's an easy fix -- change `dateFormat` to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Printing out an `NSDate` in `yyyy-MM-dd` format is also an easy fix. Just as you used `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFromString()` method to convert a string whose format is specified by its `dateFormat` property into an `NSDate`, use `NSDateFormatter`'s **`stringFromDate()`** method to convert an `NSDate` into a string with `dateFormat`'s format.

Here's your code, with these two fixes applied:

```
var survey_date = prefs.valueForKey("SURVEY_DATE") as! String

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(survey_date) as NSDate!
let outputDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

println(outputDate)

self.survey_date.text = "Your survey is scheduled for \(outputDate)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code using a date formatter is correct, and is actually working correctly.

Date formatters default to the user's current time zone, so the date you enter as "2015-05-27" will be assumed to be midnight (I think) on that day in your local time zone.

Println displays the date in UTC, so you are seeing the output in UTC. Apparently you are in UTC+1, so the date shows up as 11:00 PM the day before.

You can use another date formatter to output your date as a string in your local time zone in whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reading other answers on this site, it appears that Swift doesn’t have a native Date object but you can instead use the Cocoa `NSDate` object:

```
var date = Date.parse("2014-05-20")
```

The second parameter is format, which defaults to `yyyy-MM-dd` (which is what MySQL dates are).

I imagine once you have a `NSDate` object you’ll then be able to print it in a format of your choosing.

Comment: My problem is getting var survey_date = prefs.valueForKey("SURVEY_DATE") as! String to convert to NSDate

Comment: If you look above, the first parameter of `Date.parse` is a string, so cast your MySQL date to a string and then pass it into the `parse` method.